# Paper-Button is not working in polymer..?

Tags: html, angularjs, web, polymer

I created Paper-button but its not working on my web-browser.I tried many ways to solve but didn't work.Here are snaps Of all code and library.
Thanks.

[image: ImageofCode]

[image: ImageOfSource]

[image: OutPutofpaper-button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start work with Polymer elements you need to import main Polymer file into your index.html before use and include `paper-button` :

`<link rel="import" href="Your Path/polymer-starter-kit/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">`

and also include polyfills `webcomponents.js` for browsers support:

`<script src="Your Path/polymer-starter-kit/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>`

Comment: With your path all ok?

Comment: Ya its perfect. I checked it twice

Comment: Do you have any errors in console with import Polymer and polyfills  and without it's   ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t46kqo04m82sfoa/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-27%20at%201.07.48%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: The link of my console snap

Comment: it's working now thanks. after adding the script i restart the eclipse and its working now.